Wordpress WP_Query meta_query problem and solution using posts_clauses hook
I met an "deficiency" in Wordpress WP_Query query with complex meta_query.
For example, with two meta_keys 'ev-date-start' and 'ev-date-end', searching posts starting after date or ending after date :
'meta_query' => [
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'ev-date-start' => [ 
        'key' => 'ev-date-start',
        'value' => wp_date('Y-m-d'),
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ],
    'ev-date-end' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key' => 'ev-date-end',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'ev-date-end',
            'value' => wp_date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ]
    ]
],
'orderby' => [
    'ev-date-start' => 'ASC',
],


Due to OR relation, in SQL request I found that in WHERE clause the meta_key test could be never executed.
( wor5504_postmeta.meta_key = 'ev-date-start' AND wor5504_postmeta.meta_value > DATE )
OR
( mt1.meta_key = 'ev-date-end' AND mt1.meta_value > DATE )
ORDER BY wor5504_postmeta.meta_value


I found, as a symptom, that ORDER BY sql treatment failed because of a DATE casting.
My solution above as an answer...

If your intention here was to show a solution, then please do that while still following the Q&A format of this site: Ask a question first, and then write a self-answer.

My solution is to use posts_clauses hook to insert into JOIN clause the meta_key testing.
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'on_posts_clauses_meta_query', 10, 2 );
$posts = get_posts( $query );
remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'on_posts_clauses_meta_query', 10, 2 );

/***********************************************************/
/**
 * WP_Query hack for meta_query
 * Duplicate "meta_key = 'xxx'" from WHERE clause into JOIN clause for each postmeta
 */
function on_posts_clauses_meta_query( $clauses, $query){
    global $wpdb;
    
    $postmeta = $wpdb->postmeta;
    
    //JOIN clause aliases
    $matches = [];
    $pattern = sprintf('/(%s)(\sAS\s(\w+))?\sON\s/i', preg_quote($postmeta));
    if( preg_match_all( $pattern, $clauses['join'], $matches ) ){
        $aliases = [];
        $aliases_pattern = '';
        foreach( $matches[3] as $index => $alias ){
            if( $alias === '' )
                $alias = $postmeta;
            if( array_key_exists($alias, $aliases) )
                continue;
            $aliases[$alias] = $matches[0][$index];
            if( $aliases_pattern )
                $aliases_pattern .= '|';
            $aliases_pattern .= preg_quote($alias);
        }
        
        // search in WHERE clause for alias.meta_key = 'xxx'
        $pattern = sprintf('/(%s)\.meta_key\s=\s\'([^\']+)\'/', $aliases_pattern);
        if( preg_match_all( $pattern, $clauses['where'], $matches ) ){
            foreach( $matches[1] as $index => $alias ){
                /*INNER JOIN wor5504_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wor5504_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  
                becomes
                INNER JOIN wor5504_postmeta AS mt1 ON  mt1.meta_key = 'ev-date-end' AND ( wor5504_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  */
                $join_clause = sprintf('%s %s AND ', $aliases[$alias], $matches[0][$index]);
                if( strpos( $clauses['join'], $join_clause ) === false )
                    $clauses['join'] = str_replace( $aliases[$alias], $join_clause, $clauses['join']);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $clauses;
}


